# Lucee - How to setup virtual sites and access the web administrator?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I'm using current Lucee on W2K16 with IIS.  I installed Lucee and created a test site (test.lucee.xyz), added that to my hosts file and can browse it locally and everything seems to work.

I now added a 2nd site.  Added through IIS as normal and then I edited

```
D:\lucee\tomcat\conf\server.xml
```

For my 2nd site I added a host:

```
<Host name="mango.tuitionrewards.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"  xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
   <Context path="" docBase="D:\webroot\luceetest.mysite.com" />
   <Alias>luceetest.mysite.com</Alias>
</Host>
```

Saved that, restarted Lucee and now have a WEB-INF folder in the site root:

```
D:\webroot\luceetest.mysite.com\WEB-INF
```

This site now works as well.

My question is it's my understanding that in the Lucee Administrator the Server tab is global, and the Web tab is specific to one site.  For me, when I go into the Administrator, the URLs are:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/lucee/admin/server.cfm?action=overview
http://127.0.0.1:8888/lucee/admin/web.cfm?action=overview
```

How do I get the "web" Administrator to interact with the new site?  Also is it safe to remove the first test site (test.lucee.xyz)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you installed Lucee using the Lucee Installer, and you selected the option to install mod_cfml and the BonCode Connector, all you need to do is create a site in IIS, and manage them like you normally would in IIS.

mod_cfml will dynamically create the site contexts in Tomcat for you at runtime. You can create the contexts in the server.xml if you want to (this will start those contexts during Tomcat's startup cycle instead of at runtime), but the end result is the same.

From there, you would access each site's web administrator from that site's URL:

```
https://luceetest.mysite.com/lucee/admin/web.cfm?action=overview
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So assuming I have the mod_cfml (I know BonCode is there) I don't need to force the /web-inf into each site's root via the server.xml file?  I'll work on it some more tomorrow.

Comment: just did a fresh install and I'm clearly missing something.  I added a site in IIS, restarted Tomcat/Lucee and IIS but it's just a static site.  Is there something else I need to configure so that mod_cfml "sees" that I'm adding sites outside of the Lucee root (d:\sites\site_1) as opposed to d:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\root?

Comment: What are you getting when you hit the new site's index.cfm file? Maybe more clearly define what you mean by "static site"? Hitting the index.cfm should have IIS pass the request to BonCode (as a handler) then to Tomcat, then to Lucee. The part where mod_cfml creates the new context should happen the first time a new context request hits Tomcat. So, let me know what's happening now and we can figure out where in the process things might be off. HTH

Comment: I figured it out - stupid mistake.  Once I fixed that the WEB-INF was created and cfm pages work fine.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Glad you figured it out. =) For posterity, what else did you need to do? If it can help someone else, then it's worth noting. Thanks Steve!

Comment: Almost too embarrassed to answer....Created a static index.htm file just to test IIS after doing some lockdown.  Added a writeOutput(now()); - but left the extension .htm....

Comment: Nice. Don't worry about it. Anyone who reads this will probably be a programmer like us, and, to quote a great verse, "Let him who is without sin cast the first stone". IE: we've all had facepalm moments like that. Thanks for sharing!